# Displaying the selected multiple values below the text box

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to display the selected values of the text box and display the selected values below the text box.

The textbox below can accept multiple values and it can be deleted by clicking x symbol on the value. It will be just like the way we add recipients in facebook while sending a message.

Once the user start typing in the textbox, there will be suggestions to choose from.

This way the values are added in the textbox.

Now i want to display the selected multiple values in the div below the textbox. By the javascript code i wrote, it displays only one value. but i want to display the multiple values which could be slected and the values should disappear once they are removed from the text box. please correct me where am making the mistake.

```
function takeVal(val)
        {
    var str='';
    <?
        $query = "select * from product";
        $sql = mysql_query($query);
        while($rs = mysql_fetch_object($sql))
        {
    ?>  
        if('<?php echo $rs->id;?>' == val)
        {

        //str += '<?php echo $rs->name;?>';
            document.getElementById('selectedResult').innerHTML = "The selected number is - " + "<?php echo $rs->name;?>";
        }

    <?
        }
    ?>

        }
```

HTML

```
 <input type="text" id="interestedin" name="" class="box2 validate[required]"OnChange="takeVal(this.value);"/>
<div id='selectedResult'></div>
```

Comment: Since the value i get is only the id. I wrote query to take the corresponding name

Comment: Have you tried any of the answers yet? If so: did they answer your question/solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a very crude way to implement autocomplete (no offence). Have you considered using a plugin for one of the many JS frameworks out there? For example, jQuery UI offers a fairly robust autocomplete plugin by default: [jQuery UI AutoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

Using that, your problem would be very easy to solve:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var products = [
            <?php // PHP begins here
                $query = "select * from product";
                $sql = mysql_query($query);
                while($rs = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {
                    echo '"', $rs->name, '",';
                } // PHP ends here
            ?>
        ];
        $( "#interestedin" ).autocomplete({
            source: products,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#selectedResult').text(ui.item.value);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="text" id="interestedin" class="box2 validate[required]" />
<div id="selectedResult"></div>
```

Comment: Am sorry PPvG . I couldn't try it so far cuz i was stuffed with other works in my work place. i will try it tonight and update the results as soon as posible. thank you so much for your timely resposes and help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

the $rs->id is an array, use any a for or foreach statement to loop through it.